# run function with uniquie value using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

```js
let object=
    [
     {
      id:`01`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:null,
      care:'owner',
     },
     {
      id:`02`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:'fresh',
      care:'peter',
     },
     {
      id:`03`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`fresh`,
      care:'amy',
     },
     {
      id:`04`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`tank`,
      care:'abc',
     },
     {
      id:`05`,
      name:`animal`,
      type:`pet`,
      care:'teen',
     },,
     {
      id:`06`,
      name:`animal`,
      type:`pet`,
      care:'ran',
     },
     {
      id:`07`,
      name:`animal`,
      type:null,
      care:'roh',
     },
     {
      id:`08`,
      name:`food`,
      type:`veg`,
      care:'test',
     },
     {
      id:`09`,
      name:`food`,
      type:null,
      care:'dop',
     }
    ]
    
    object.map((value)=>{
console.log(value.name)

// i am calling function here by passing value.name as a parameter
   let gotValue = functionName(value.name);

 // using type also 
 if(typeof value.type!=="string"){
// Do some task here with gotValue

  }
})
```

I have this object and i am getting some value from it for ex getting name from it as i want to pass this name to function but the problem is due to repeat of data the function calling again and again is there any possibility i can run function inside map but with unique value any help ?

- as my output is getting like this

```
fish
fish
fish
animal
animal
animal
```

and this value.name is passing inside my function so its repeating like this

```
functionName(fish);
functionName(fish);
functionName(fish);
functionName(animal);
functionName(animal);
functionName(animal);
```

multiple time function is running with same name and getting duplicate values

- just need my function run with unique name

```
functionName(fish)
functionName(animal);
functionName(food);
```

- as i want to stay inside map function because i am performing some task which can only be possible inside map that's why i need unique value

Comment: Use `Set` for unique values

Comment: If you're not going to use the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> What is the expected output/result? And what's the actual problem?

Comment: `[...new Set(object.map((o) => o.name))].forEach(functionName);` if `functionName` takes the `name` as input.

Comment: @decpk i have to write this inside map function ?

Comment: as Andreas already said if you're not returning something from the map then don't use the map. It is an alternative.

Comment: yes i am not returning anything but need values which are present inside for eg : i need `type` value to and type value are unique but problem is with name as they are keep repeating and i want name unique inside map function only @decpk

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look in snippet :)

Comment: How are you calculating that the object is unique? Is it on the basis of `name` or `name and type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which can be used to test if the object with value already exists or not. It will only call the function only once.

```js
let object = [
  {
    id: `01`,
    name: `fish`,
    type: null,
  },
  {
    id: `02`,
    name: `fish`,
    type: `fresh`,
  },
  {
    id: `03`,
    name: `fish`,
    type: `tank`,
  },
  {
    id: `04`,
    name: `animal`,
    type: `pet`,
  },
  {
    id: `05`,
    name: `animal`,
    type: `wild`,
  },
  {
    id: `06`,
    name: `animal`,
    type: null,
  },
  {
    id: `07`,
    name: `food`,
    type: `veg`,
  },
  {
    id: `08`,
    name: `food`,
    type: null,
  },
];

const dict = new Set();
object.map((value) => {
  if (!dict.has(value.name)) { // Run only if objet with name is not already existed in dict
    dict.add(value.name);
    console.log(value.name); // For testing
    // functionName(value.name);
  }
});
```

If you want to call the function with two filters then you can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to find the elements in an array. **See I've now declared dict as an array**

```js
let object = [{
    id: `01`,
    name: `fish`,
    type: null,
  },
  {
    id: `02`,
    name: `fish`,
    type: `fresh`,
  },
  {
    id: `03`,
    name: `fish`,
    type: `tank`,
  },
  {
    id: `04`,
    name: `animal`,
    type: `pet`,
  },
  {
    id: `05`,
    name: `animal`,
    type: `wild`,
  },
  {
    id: `06`,
    name: `animal`,
    type: null,
  },
  {
    id: `07`,
    name: `food`,
    type: `veg`,
  },
  {
    id: `08`,
    name: `food`,
    type: null,
  },
  {
    id: `09`,
    name: `food`,
    type: null,
  },
  {
    id: `10`,
    name: `fish`,
    type: `tank`,
  },
];

const dict = [];
object.map((value) => {
  const { name, type } = value;
  if (!dict.some((obj) => obj.name === name && obj.type === type)) {
    // Run only if objet with name is not already existed in dict
    dict.push({ name, type });
    console.log(name, type); // For testing
    // functionName(value.name);
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: hey sorry to disturb you @decpk but if i want to check with both `value.name` and `value.test` do i need to do like this ?? `if ( !dict.has(value.name) && (value.test)) `

Comment: what is `value.test`? There  is no property with `test`.

Comment: Answer updated and you can also use for single filter also then you don't need to use `Set`. Hope this is exactly what you want...

Comment: you can see i have updated my qstn for more clarification as i have some `name` n `type` but with different `care` value and sorry i was typing `value.type` mistakenly typed `value.test` so i want to store value of care if name and type repeated like you made for name when it was repeating

Comment: what if 2 objects with the same `name`, `type` and `care`

Comment: care is different in my database